# Slow Multithreading in Java - Air Percussion project

Tags: java, multithreading, javasound

I am creating "Air Percussion" using IMU sensors and Arduino to communicate with computer (3 separate IMUs and Arduinos). They are connected to the computer through USBs. I am gathering data on separate Threads (each thread for each sensor). When I connect only one "set" my program is working really fast. I can get even 5 plays of sound per second. Unfortunatelly when i am trying to connect 3 sensors and run them on separate Threads at the same time my program slows down horribly. Even when im moving only one of sensors, I can get like 1 "hit" per second and sometimes it's even losing some of the sounds it should play. I'll show only important parts of the code below.

In the main i've got ActionListener for button, where it should start gathering the data. I run there 3 separate Threads for each USB Port.

```
connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int dialogButton = 1;
        if(!flagaKalibracjiLewa || !flagaKalibracjiPrawa){ //some unimportant flags
            dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Rozpoczynając program bez kalibracji będziesz miał do dyspozycji mniejszą ilość dzwięków. Czy chcesz kontynuować?","Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }else{
            dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
        }
        if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            if(connectButton.getText().equals("Connect")) {
                if(!flagaKalibracjiLewa && !flagaKalibracjiPrawa) podlaczPorty();
                Thread thread = new Thread(){
                    @Override public void run() {
                        Scanner data = new Scanner(chosenPort.getInputStream());
                        dataIncoming(data, "lewa");
                        data.close();
                    }
                };
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(){
                    @Override public void run() {
                        Scanner data = new Scanner(chosenPort2.getInputStream());
                        dataIncoming(data, "prawa");
                        data.close();
                    }
                };
                Thread thread3 = new Thread(){
                    @Override public void run() {
                        Scanner data = new Scanner(chosenPort3.getInputStream());
                        dataIncoming(data, "stopa");
                        data.close();
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
                thread2.start();
                thread3.start();
                connectButton.setText("Disconnect");
            } else {
                // disconnect from the serial port
                chosenPort.closePort();
                chosenPort2.closePort();
                chosenPort3.closePort();
                portList.setEnabled(true);
                portList2.setEnabled(true);
                portList3.setEnabled(true);
                connectButton.setText("Connect");
            }
        }             
    }
});
```

in "dataIncoming" method there is bunch of not important things (like picking, which sound should be played etc.). The important part is in the while loop. In the "while" im gathering next lines of data from sensor. When one of the values is higher than something it should play a sound but only if some time has passed and the sensor has moved a certain way. (when the drumstick is going down the "imuValues[4]" is increasing, when its going up its decreasing, so when its past 160 it means that the player has taken the drumstick up so its ready for the next hit)

```
while(data.hasNextLine()) {
    try{
        imuValues = data.nextLine().split(",");
        if(Double.parseDouble(imuValues[4])>200 && flagaThreada) {
            flagaThreada = false;
            playSound(sound1);
        }
        if(Double.parseDouble(imuValues[4])<160 && System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime>100) {   
            flagaThreada = true;
            startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
}
```

and finally the method for playing the sound is :

```
public static synchronized void playSound(String sound) {
    try {
        String url = "/sounds/"+sound+".wav";
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
        Main.class.getResourceAsStream(url));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR IN OPENING");
    }
}
```

Is my computer to slow to compute and play sounds for 3 sensors at the same time? Or is there a way to create those Threads in a better fashion?

Comment: The `synchronized` in `playSound(..)` prevents starting more than one clip at once. Not sure why you sync that. But that aside, I would create all `Clip` *once* during initialization and then simply play them repeatedly. That way you don't have to re-read from disk, every time you "hit" something.

Comment: I've moved initialization of all the Clips to the begining of the program, now in `playSound(..)` I am only calling certain clip.start(). Unfortunatelly after doing this every clip plays only once. Can't replay it.

Comment: I've added 'clip.setFramePosition(0)' and now its repeating sound. I've also removed "synchronized" but its still losing some "hits" when more than one sensor is connected.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the playback of the sound is actually the problem? E.g. instead of playing the sound, you could just print something to `System.out` instead. Does that work as expected?

Comment: I've tried printing something out and its not the problem with the sound. I think its the problem with Threads.

Comment: Ok I've fixed it. The problem was that each sensor was sending like 60 lines of data per second. When running on 3 ports at the same time it was just to much for the computer to work with those numbers. I've moved all the math calculating if the sound should be played or not to the Arduino code. Now each sensor calculates on its own if the sound should be played and if yes, it's sending message "play sound xyz" on its port. Now three threads can work together and nothing is lagging. Anyway, thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a version of Clip, called AudioCue, which allows multi-threading on the play commands. It is open source, BSD license (free), consists of three files which you can cut and paste into your program. There is also an API link for it. More info at [AudioCue](http://adonax.com/AudioCue/). The site has code examples as well as link to API and source code. There is also some dialogue about its use at Java-gaming.org, under the "Sound" topic thread.

The basic principle behind the code is to make the audio data available in a float array, and send multiple, independent "cursors" through it (one per play command). The setup lets us also do real time volume fading, pitch changes and panning. The audio is output via a SourceDataLine which you can configure (set thread priority, buffer size).

I'm maybe a week or two away from sharing a more advanced version that allows all AudioCues to be mixed through a single output line. This version has five classes/interfaces instead of three, and is being set up for release on github. I'm also hoping to get a donate button and the like set up for this next iteration. The next version might be more useful for Arduino in that I believe you are only allowed up to 8 audio outputs on that system.

Other than that, the steps you have taken (separating the open from the play, using setFramePosition for restarts) are correct. I can't think of anything else to add to help out besides writing your own mixer/cue player (as I have done and am willing to share).